# Echo specific value in array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to echo specific value in array inside another array.

```
 array (size=5)
      'answer' => string 'February12' (length=10)
      'submitted' => 
        array (size=3)
          'full_name' => string 'Sander' (length=6)
          'age' => string '20' (length=2)
          'email' => string 'brtwers@fze.com' (length=15)
      'why' => string 'sfsdf' (length=5)
      'games' => string 'zefzef' (length=6)
      'help' => string 'zerzer' (length=6)
```

For example I want the value from email.

This is the result of a post so I was thinking something like this

```
echo $_POST['submitted['email']'];
```

but that is not working. What should be the correct syntax?

Comment: You almost had it - `$_POST['submitted']['email']`

Comment: Jup thanks, stupid of me that I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
echo $_POST['submitted']['email'];
```